# How to use JS to detect the availability of pseudo-elements in a browser?

Tags: javascript, css

Pseudo-elements like

- ::selection
- ::inactive-selection
- ::spelling-error
- ::grammar-error
- ::marker
- ::placeholder
- ::backdrop

Comment: Use https://modernizr.com/.